# PHP Simple Template Engine / Function

Tags: php, templates, preg-replace

I'm required to create a simple template engine; I can't use Twig or Smarty, etc. because the designer on the project needs to be able to just copy/paste her HTML into the template with no configuration, muss/fuss, whatever. It's gotta be **really** easy.

So I created something that will allow her to do just that, by placing her content between `{{ CONTENT }}` `{{ !CONTENT }}` tags.

My only problem is that I want to make sure that if she uses multiple spaces in the tags - or NO spaces - it won't break; i.e. `{{   CONTENT   }}` or `{{CONTENT}}`

What I have below accomplishes this, but I'm afraid it may be overkill. Anybody know a way to simplify this function?

```
function defineContent($tag, $string) {

    $offset = strlen($tag) + 6;

    // add a space to our tags if none exist
    $string = str_replace('{{'.$tag, '{{ '.$tag, $string);
    $string = str_replace($tag.'}}', $tag.' }}', $string);

    // strip consecutive spaces
    $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);

    // now that extra spaces have been stripped, we're left with this
    // {{ CONTENT }} My content goes here {{ !CONTENT }}

    // remove the template tags
    $return = substr($string, strpos($string, '{{ '.$tag.' }}') + $offset);
    $return = substr($return, 0, strpos($return, '{{ !'.$tag.' }}'));

    return $return;
}

// here's the string
$string  = '{{     CONTENT  }} My content   goes here  {{ !CONTENT   }}';

// run it through the function
$content = defineContent('CONTENT', $string);

echo $content;

// gives us this...
My content goes here
```

#### EDIT

Ended up creating a repo, for anyone interested.

https://github.com/timgavin/tinyTemplate

Comment: I think she can simple learn what to ignore (your loops, conditions, etc...+ you can use alternative syntax, to make things easier: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) Imho, you don't need this at all... but, that's just me... :)

Comment: @nevermind this goes beyond just the `CONTENT` tag, she'll need access to many parts of the page with many tags, and if I clutter it up with too much PHP she'll lose her shit. :)

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest to take a look at variable extraction into the template scope.
It's a bit easier to maintain and less overhead, than the replace approach and its often easier to use for the designer. In its basic form, its just PHP variables and short tags.

It depends on which side you generate, e.g. a table and its rows (or complete content blocks) - it could be just `<?=$table?>` ;) Less work for the designer, more work for you. Or just provide a few rendering examples and helpers, because copy/pasting examples should always work, even with an untrained designer.

**Template**

The template is just HTML mixed with `<?=$variable?>` - uncluttered.

`src/Templates/Article.php`

```
<html>
 <body>
 <h1><?=$title?></h1>
 <div><?=$content?></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Usage**

`src/Controller/Article.php`

```
...

// initalize
$view = new View;

// assign
$view->data['title'] = 'The title';
$view->data['content'] = 'The body';

// render
$view->render(dirname(__DIR__) . '/Templates/Article.php');
```

**View / TemplateRenderer**

The core function here is `render()`. The template file is included and the variable extraction happens in a closure to avoid any variable clashes/scope problems.

`src/View.php`

```
class View
{
    /**
     * Set data from controller: $view->data['variable'] = 'value';
     * @var array
     */
    public $data = [];

    /**
     * @var sting Path to template file.
     */ 
    function render($template)
    {
        if (!is_file($template)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Template not found: ' . $template);
        }

        // define a closure with a scope for the variable extraction
        $result = function($file, array $data = array()) {
            ob_start();
            extract($data, EXTR_SKIP);
            try {
                include $file;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                ob_end_clean();
                throw $e;
            }
            return ob_get_clean();
        };

        // call the closure
        echo $result($template, $this->data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering specifically what you asked:

> My only problem is that I want to make sure that if she uses multiple spaces in the tags - or NO spaces - it won't break
>
> What I have below accomplishes this, but I'm afraid it may be overkill. Anybody know a way to simplify this function?

... the only "slow" part of your function is the `preg_replace`.  Use **[trim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)** instead, for a very slight increase in speed.  Otherwise, don't worry about it. There's no magic PHP command to do what you're looking to do.